# Applescript - ghosted result with applescript set file label

Tags: applescript, macos-mojave, macos-catalina

I did make this script in automator.

```
property unset : 0
property orange : 1
property red : 2
property yellow : 3
property blue : 4
property purple : 5
property green : 6
property grey : 7

property tmplFileName : "__ReadMe" as string
property fileType : ".txt" as string
property labelTag : red

on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Finder"

    set currentPath to insertion location as text
    -- set filePath to POSIX path of currentPath
    set txtfilename to tmplFileName & fileType
    set txtFile to make new file at insertion location as alias with properties {name:txtfilename}
    set the label index of the item (txtFile as alias) to my labelTag

    select txtFile
    open txtFile

end tell

return input
end run
```

It give's me the following result. A ghosted or visible only disabled file.

[image: the textfile is ghosted.]

What do I wrong? This happens only when I set the label. Its about this line

```
set the label index of the item (txtFile as alias) to my labelTag
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: That should stop the script I guess, but the script is already ended, and the file is still un-selectable. And why a -1, can someone explain.

Comment: Guess what, I did this. Still there, but what is the code solution to have it right.

Comment: Nope, every where. In my User folder, on a diff USB drive, on a attached TB3 device and also on a NAS afp. Is there a way to reload the finder? But still like to know why a -1?

Comment: Strange, Matt, some of your reactions are gone. Deleted?

Comment: I do get a notification that there is an app that is using that file when I try to delete it.  - Should I go with tag's instead of Labels? Any suggestions how to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

Still don't understand why the file is disabled. Anyway and moving forward, after some reading I came with this as a test script, and it works. Need some error management like check existing file.

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

property |NSURL| : a reference to current application's NSURL

property tmplFileName : "__ReadMe" as string
property fileType : ".txt" as string
property labelTag : "red"

-- Replace tags; 
--      setTags - pass a list with new tags and replacing any existing
--      forPath - POSIX path

on setTags:tagList forPath:POSIXPath 
    set aURL to current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:POSIXPath
    aURL's setResourceValue:tagList forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value)
end setTags:forPath:

on run {input, parameters}

  tell application "Finder"

    set txtfilename to tmplFileName & fileType
    set txtFile to make new file at insertion location as alias with properties {name:txtfilename}
    set POSIXPath to POSIX path of (txtFile as text)
    (my setTags:{labelTag} forPath:POSIXPath)
    select txtFile

    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        open txtFile as alias
    end tell

  end tell

  return input
end run
```

Hope this help some other people as well. Do I get now a plus one vote back from above. As a side note, can some one explain why I did get a -1? just curious.
Thank you.

Comment: That _is_ strange.  It looks like an extended attribute is getting corrupted or something, as just creating the file and trying to set the tag with `Get Info` has the same result (removing the `FinderInfo` attribute or opening/closing the file seems to fix it).  Not sure why you were downvoted, unless it was for the script not working in the **Script Editor**, although you did mention that it was created in **Automator**.

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab in the dark and thought maybe the problem was the size of the file that was created, was 0 kb's. I decided to add a handler with the `write to file` command and added a single space as a character to the file.  This made the file size 1 byte and then setting the label index worked.  I made a few minor adjustments to your initial code, for my purposes but here are the changes I've made and my version of the code.

```
local unset, orange, red, yellow, blue, purple, green, grey

set {unset, orange, red, yellow, blue, purple, green, grey} to {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

set tmplFileName to "__ReadMe"
set nameExtension to ".txt"
set labelTag to red

tell application "Finder"
    set currentPath to insertion location
    set txtfilename to tmplFileName & nameExtension
    set txtFile to make new file at insertion location as alias with properties {name:txtfilename, name extension:nameExtension}

    my writeToTheFile(txtFile as alias)

    set the label index of (txtFile as alias) to labelTag

    open txtFile
end tell

on writeToTheFile(txtFile as alias)
    set theFile to txtFile as alias
    set theText to " "
    try
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        write theText to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    on error errMsg number errNum
        try
            close access theFile
        end try
    end try
end writeToTheFile
```

Comment: on macOS Catilina, the script fails sometimes but not always at `my writeToFile(txtFile as alias)` with `error "«script» doesn’t understand the “writeToFile” message." number -1708 from «script»`. It also can create the same issue as in the OP, the file being grayed out and not accessible, [as in this picture](https://imgur.com/a/eoOm0RE).

Comment: Also. I've mentioned this to you before about repeating the same _code_ in the `on error` _handler_ that you have in the `try` _block_ You should have `close access theFile` and not try to write to it again, that's not the proper way to deal with an I/O write error!

Comment: @user3439894  I made some minor changes and updated my code. With both operating systems (Mojave and Catalina), as long as the "__ReadMe.txt" file did not already exist at the insertion location,  I ran multiple tests and it did not throw a single error.  Let me know if my changes made a difference on your end.

Comment: Thank you. A side question to extend the above scripts is there a way to check in Applescript to check if a file is actually open, like lsof?

Comment: To no one specific, or everyone, I would suggest (actually, I preach this constantly), to handle as many file operations as possible with System Events. It handles POSIX paths, the tilde, doesn't error making a file that already exists, and might not have the ghosting which sounds like a Finder flustercluck. Finder is only needed for insertion location and label index.

Comment: @LordAnubis As far as I know, AppleScript can't tell you if a file is open.  A file being opened is usually not the file itself otherwise only one application could read or write to it at any one time like in the olden days.